# Why does my window not show?

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I need to write a `GrabWindow`, so I derived my class `GrabWindow` from `QQuickWindow`:

```
#include <QtQuickWidgets/QtQuickWidgets>
#include <QString>

class GrabWindow : public QQuickWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GrabWindow(QQuickWindow *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void capture(QString const &path);
};
// .CPP
#include "grab_window.h"
#include <QImage>

GrabWindow::GrabWindow(QQuickWindow *parent) : QQuickWindow(parent) {

}

void GrabWindow::capture(const QString &path) {
    QImage img = this->grabWindow();
    img.save(path);
}
```

After I registered it in QML: `qmlRegisterType<GrabWindow>("myapp", 1, 0, "GrabWindow");`
And after I defined my window in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import myapp 1.0

GrabWindow {
    id : translationWindow
    width : 1024
    height : 768
    color: "transparent"
    visibility: "FullScreen"
    visible: true;
    signal capture(string path)

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: translationWindow.capture("/home/user/saveTest.jpg")
    }
}
```

But it doesn't show on start (I know it's transparent, I mean the grab window doesn't start to show). If instead of `GrabWindow` I use `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` then all works perfectly I am seeing a transparent full-screen window.
What's wrong?

Comment: The problem is with QQuickWindow window flags that affect its transparency or so.

Comment: @AlexanderV, I need to it was transparent and `Window` works with same flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GrabWindow` is not shown because when you are setting the `visible` property it's not same as when you use `Window`'s `visible` property.

Yours is just the `visible` property of `QWindow`.
`Window` does not directly instantiate `QQuickWindow`, it instantiates a private Qt class `QQuickWindowImpl` which overrides the `visible` property with a custom one.
It seems to delay the actual call of the `QWindow::setVisible` at a later time.

As such, I don't think `QQuickWindow` is meant to be inherited from. You could try doing `visible = true` in your `Component.onCompleted` but I'm not sure it will resolve your problem.

What I would advise you instead is not subclassing `QQuickWindow` but just creating a new type and pass it the existing `Window`.

Possible API could be :

```
Window {
    id: myWindow
    //...
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: WindowGrabber.grab(myWindow, path) //singleton type
    }
}
```

or

```
Window {
    id: myWindow
    //...
    WindowGrabber { // regular type
        id: windowGrabber
        window: myWindow
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: windowGrabber.grab(path) // you could even add a path property in WindowGrabber and not have it as a function parameter if that makes sense for your use case
    }
}
```